# Merge C# list elements based on attribute of the object

Tags: c#, list, join, element

I have a list in C#. List where User object has few parameters. username, age something like that. 
In the list there are duplicate (only twice) entities according to the username. Eventhoug the usernames are same, other attributes are not same.

How can I merge those elements and remove duplications of elements in that list.

P.S:  Eventhough there are duplicate entities according to the username, other atteributes empty in one element and other element has the values for those attributes.

Comment: Hi, is this a List<Dictionary<string, string>> or something similar?

Comment: You will need clearer rules and specifications. What if Age has 2 different vales? What is the truth then?

Comment: Do you really have a spec that when an item is filled in A then it will be empty in B ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var duplicates = Users
    .GroupBy(u => u.UserName)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .ToList();
```

Each member is now an IEnumerable with the same UserName

```
foreach(var duplicate in duplicates)
{
   // write some logic to combine >= 2 Users
   // and remove all but 1 from original Users

   // a rough idea:
   var main = duplicate.First();
   foreach(var user in duplicate.Skip(1))
   {
      // merge user with main
      ....
      toDeleteList.Add(user);
   }
}
```

Comment: Usernames are ususally normalized, but if that is a problem: `.GroupBy(u => u.UserName.ToLower())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a IEqualityComparer

```
internal class UserEqualChecker : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    public bool Equals(User x, User y)
    {
        //Code for what makes them equal
        //for instance 
        return x.UserName.Equals(y.UserName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    //.....
}
```

And then...

```
var list = new List<User>();
//put the data into the list...
list.Distinct(new UserEqualChecker());
```

This way, you have a reusable comparer

Comment: Distinct gives you the list without duplicates...
...ok, the list have to be filled with data off cource

Answer (score 0):

You can group your list using linq and then create a new object with your merged data:

```
var merged = from item in mylist
             group item by item.UserName into grp
             select new YourClass { 
                 Username = grp.Key,
                 Proeperty1 = grp.Where(g => g.Porperty1 != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Property2 = ...
             }
```

This assume usernames are CaseSensitive, you can change the group by using UserName.Toupper() or something similar...

As @HenkHolterman said, you have to define how select values for your properties.

The rule i wrote for Prperty1 is only an example...